# Error pushing to GitLab: "Possible DNS spoofing detected!"

Tags: git, gitlab

I got this error while pushing my code to Gitlab. Can you please help me with what this means and what might have caused this ?

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

The RSA host key for gitlab.xyz.com has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 142.23.29.11
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
```

Comment: If you read through the message, you will find that it literally says what is happening. Could you maybe edit your question so it's clear what you are asking?

Comment: Duplicate of [Not able to “git pull” - Host key verification failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087695/not-able-to-git-pull-host-key-verification-failed).