# Can't execute git command in nodejs

Tags: linux, node.js, git

I can successfully execute `git pull` in linux command line on my VPS, but when I execute a bash file containing "`git pull`" with execFile in Nodejs, it gave me an error: `Command failed: Host key verification failed.` How can I solve this problem?

Update: 
The whole error message I get is:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read 
from remote  repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

It seems that it's not the same problem with the question dylants provided.

The bash file script is like this, I use it to auto deploy my nodejs app:

```
git pull && pm2 reload www
```

I am using ssh protocol instead of https protocol on my vps in order to prevent the password prompt each time I `git pull` from my bitbucket repository. So ssh keys were generated in my user directory `~/.ssh/`. I think the reason why nodejs failed to execute the bash file is this:  The user who run the bash file in nodejs app is different from the user who run the bash file in command line. so the user running nodejs can't use the ssh keys located in `~/.ssh` for verification.

Is that right? How to fix it?

Comment: Is there more to the error than just that?  This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087695/not-able-to-git-pull-host-key-verification-failed

Comment: Pls add to question bash file script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have correctly identified the problem: the nodejs application does not have access to your ssh credentials.  You have a few options available:

- If you can make the repository available for anonymous read-only access via http:// or git:// protocols, you can have the nodejs pull changes without requiring any sort of credentials.
- You can generate an ssh key for the nodejs user and grant that user read-only access to the repository.  You would just need to generate an ssh keypair in the appropriate location for that user.
- You could drop your own credentials where your nodejs app can make use of them, but this has a number of security problems -- if your webapp is compromised, the attacker can write changes to your repository that will appear to come from you.  So don't use this option.

Comment: Problem solved. My nodejs app is running by the root user, I generated a deploy key for it(https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+deployment+keys), now everything is alright, Thanks.